# AutoMatically Creating New Sites When New Users Sign Up

Tags: looking-for-a-script, tools

I would like to know how hosted eCommerce sites like www.shopify.com, www.3dCart.com etc.. automatically creates new sites when new users sign up. What kind of tools do they use to create those sites into the users profile. I have tried googling but couldn't find an answer.

Does any of you guys have any knowledge or experience that you can share with me? Or do you know a tutorial that you can point me to?

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you need to ask you are going to have no chance of making it work and maintaining it - and I didn't even give you the (deserved) down vote.

Comment: I use NGINX, when a visitor registers and selects a subdomain we add it to a file one per line, then reload NGINX with PHP. Reloading does not mean restarting. We simply reload the configuration file. A perl script reads the list of subdomains and they are inserted to the server config file. As soon as the user registers the subdomain is created. The user still has to verify by email. They are then able to add a CNAME to their own DNS and point their domain to our server. That's one method for my application.

Comment: @Anagio :: Thanks for your reply comments. I am going to do research on NGINX. Thanks so much